# Calling file_put_contents only works once every 10 seconds

Tags: php, file, file-io

To test this out further I created a script called 'console' and made it executable. The contents of the script were the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

var_export(file_put_contents('test.txt', 'data'));
exit;
```

The output of the `var_export` was always `4` - yet if I deleted `test.txt` and ran the script again a file was only written when once every 10 seconds or so.

I'm running this script on PHP 5.5.9 on a Ubuntu Server 14.04 VM. I do not have the Zend Opcache enabled for console usage, and have confirmed that it is indeed disabled while running this script.

---

Edit: A little more information. Running this script directly on my machine (not in a VM, on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, with PHP 5.5.9) works fine, it creates the file every time without fail.

To add a little extra information, the particular shared folder that this is using in the VM is mounted via NFS.

Comment: `<bash> $ while true ; do rm test.txt; php test.php; cat test.txt; done` works as expected for me

Comment: I get the feeling it's something to do with NFS. It works fine when I run it outside the VM.